# change revsere order of xml using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

i want to reverse the order listing in my xml document file may be im doing wrong can anybody explain this why this is so im using loop and inside that loop foreach to reverse the order but not working

```
<CATALOG>
<CD>
<TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1982</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
<YEAR>1990</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
<TITLE>Eros</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY>
<PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1997</YEAR>
</CD>
</CATALOG>
```

my javascript

```
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
    var show = 
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    show.reverse();
    show.forEach(myfun);
    function myFun(xt){
    table = table + xt ;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
```

this should show first reverse order from Eros Ramazzotti ,Gary Moore, Dolly Parton, thanks.

Comment: I don't know what `show.reverse()` etc do, but I would start by changing the for loop to `for (i = x.length; i > 0; i--)`. That iterates over the CDs in reverse order.

Comment: yea i tried this aready didnt work

Comment: What's the inside loop for? Are you trying to reverse more than just the CDs?

Answer (score 0):

are you thinking of reversing the CD nodes. If yes, you can do it this way

```
var nodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
var newDoc = parser.parseFromString("<CATALOG></CATALOG>","text/xml");
var catalog = newDoc.childNodes[0];
for (var i = nodes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  catalog.appendChild(nodes[i]);
}
console.log(newDoc);
```